# how many solutions are possible for the system $x+y+z+w=30$, where $0≤x, 0≤y≤3, 0≤w≤3, 0≤z≤2$?

Tags: combinatorics

I want to find the number of solutions for the system $x+y+z+w=30$, where $0≤x, 0≤y≤3, 0≤w≤3, 0≤z≤2$.

I know that we can choose $x$ based on the sum of $w+y+z$, so I tried to calculate to number of solutions to the system $w+y+z=k$
where $0≤k≤8$ but I got stuck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's $4\times 4\times 3=48$.

This is because once you know what $y$, $w$ and $z$ are, then $x$ is determined. The restrictions on $y$, $w$ and $z$ give you $48$ choices, so there are $48$ in total.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, it seems I've overthought this problem. I'd really appreciate if you could help me with a similar problem I struggled with: 
What is the number of ways to distribute 15 indistinguishable balls to 7 kids such that each kid gets a maximum of 3 toys?